# JavaScript: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Introduce the problem before you post any code:**

I have a simple JavaScript code and it's giving me an unexpected token error. It's code that I'm trying to convert from PHP to JavaScript for use in a Phonegap application.

Specifically it is the line that declares the $ex_data variable. And it says the unexpected token is the section between the $system and $galaxy variables.

**Code**

```
for ($galaxy = 1; $galaxy < 21; $galaxy++){
            for ($system = 1; $system < 601; $system++){
                var $ex_data = '{"planet_id":-1,"sid":'.$system.',"language":"en","gid":'.$galaxy.'}';
                var $url = "http://54.193.106.113/ING004/android1/WebServer/Web/sogame/newControl/nmUniverse/getUniverse?sign=".toUpperCase($sign);     

            }
        }
```

**CLEAR QUESTION:**

How do I fix the line so that it is valid?

Comment: In JS we use `+` to concat string literals.

Comment: Usually you also don't prefix your variables with `$` in JS (even though it's a valid character in a variable name in JS).

Comment: And please... NEVER use string concatenation to build JSON data - it's a terrible thing in both PHP and JavaScript. In PHP, create an array and `json_encode()` it. In JavaScript, create an object and `JSON.stringify()` it.

Comment: Thanks for those tips! If I may ask, why is concatenation so bad for it?

Comment: @ZappTBrannigan: you probably won't be sent to hell for it, but it's usually better to use `JSON.stringify()` as you'll never accidentally make any mistakes like missing a closing brace or comma -- this is more important the larger the object is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing PHP concatenation with JavaScript (C) concatenation.

```
for ($galaxy = 1; $galaxy < 21; $galaxy++) {
        for ($system = 1; $system < 601; $system++) {
            var $ex_data = '{"planet_id":-1,"sid":'
                         . $system . ',"language":"en","gid":' . $galaxy.'}';
            var $url = "http://54.193.106.113/ING004/android1/WebServer/Web/sogame/newControl/nmUniverse/getUniverse?sign="
                       .toUpperCase($sign);     
        }
    }
```

Change the "`.`s" to "`+`s".

```
var $ex_data = '{"planet_id":-1,"sid":'
             + $system + ',"language":"en","gid":' + $galaxy + '}';
```

or alternatively

```
var $ex_data = JSON.stringify({
    "planet_id" : -1,
    "sid"       : $system,
    "language"  :"en",
    "gid"       : $galaxy
});
```

Also, as pointed out below, change `.toUpperCase($sign);` -> `+ $sign.toUpperCase();`

Comment: `toUpperCase($sign)` -- it is mistake! For JS it has to be `$sign.toUpperCase()`. You should fix it!

Answer (score 0):

```
var $ex_data = '{"planet_id":-1,"sid":' + $system + ',"language":"en","gid":' + $galaxy +'}';
var $url = "http://54.193.106.113/ING004/android1/WebServer/Web/sogame/newControl/nmUniverse/getUniverse?sign=" + $sign.toUpperCase();
```